# Laravel 5.1 query builder with 'in' clause with multiple nested OR query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am tring to convert this sql into php laravel 5.1 query.

```
SELECT `videoId`, `videoTitle`FROM `tempdetails` WHERE `videoTitle` LIKE '%Ramsays Kitchen Nightmares%' 
or videoTitle in
(
videoTitle in 
(`videoTitle` LIKE '%season 1%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%e01%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%01x%')
or
videoTitle in
(`videoTitle` LIKE '%episode 1%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%s01%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%x01%') 
)
```

This is the code I tried.

```
  $vd = DB::table('tempdetails');
               $vd ->where('videoTitle', 'like', '%'.$titl.'%')
               ->whereIn('videoTitle',function($query) {
                 $query->orwhere( 'videoTitle', 'like', '%season 1%')
                 ->orWhere( 'videoTitle', 'like', '%s01%')
                 ->orWhere( 'videoTitle', 'like', '%01x%');
               });
               $vd->whereIn('videoTitle',function($query) {
                 $query->orWhere( 'videoTitle', 'like', '%episode 1%')
                 ->orWhere( 'videoTitle', 'like', '%e01%')
               ->orWhere( 'videoTitle', 'like', '%x01%');
             });
            $vd->get();
```

But this gives me an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select *
>   from `tempdetails` where `videoTitle` like %Ramsay's Kitchen
>   Nightmares% and `videoTitle` in (select * where `videoTitle` like
>   %season 1% or `videoTitle` like %s01% or `videoTitle` like %01x%) and
>   `videoTitle` in (select * where `videoTitle` like %episode 1% or
>   `videoTitle` like %e01% or `videoTitle` like %x01%))

Anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: i'd try running the query DB::table('tempdetails')->where('blah')->wherein...->get();

Be interesting to see if it worked that way

Comment: So, sql-server or MySQL? What RDBMS? Please correct the tags.

Comment: Does Above query that you tried to convert in laravel works fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `whereRaw` or `DB::select()`. When I have complex statements that are not intuitively translatable, unless I *really* need eloquent, I prefer to run raw statement.

Also, I am not sure what your data look like and what you are trying to achieve but there might be a way to rewrite your query so it could bit better into the eloquent constraints.

Example with `whereRaw()`

```
$wherelikes = "videoTitle in
(
videoTitle in 
(`videoTitle` LIKE '%season 1%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%e01%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%01x%')
or
videoTitle in
(`videoTitle` LIKE '%episode 1%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%s01%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%x01%') 
)"
$vd = DB::table('tempdetails')
          ->whereRaw("`videoTitle` LIKE '%Ramsays Kitchen Nightmares%'")
          ->orWhere(function($query) use ($whereLikes) {
            $query->whereRaw($whereLikes)
           })->get();
```

Example with `DB::select()`

```
$statement = "SELECT `videoId`, `videoTitle`FROM `tempdetails` WHERE `videoTitle` LIKE '%Ramsays Kitchen Nightmares%' 
or videoTitle in
(
videoTitle in 
(`videoTitle` LIKE '%season 1%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%e01%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%01x%')
or
videoTitle in
(`videoTitle` LIKE '%episode 1%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%s01%' or `videoTitle` LIKE '%x01%') 
)"
$vd = DB::select(DB::raw($statement));
```

Comment: Thank you @wistar,  i used the first one and it works :) but  i put the $wherelikes='' inside the function($query){} to make it work.. :D

Comment: @kristinemay I made the edit so you do not have to use `whereLikes` inside the function